# Historical GFLOP/Watt datapoints

Tags: hardware

In preparation of a business case, I'm looking for any available data on historical GFLOP/Watt performance (preferably with specific gear included); use case here is long-term performance trends (cost of HW vs cost of electricity), preferably 1980-onwards

Any authorative sources you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do some research.

To get performance and price per watt over 40 years, you will have to compile many data sources. Find things like price of electricity in your area of the world, and adjust for inflation.

1980 is VAX 11 days, which today is a [Retrocomputing.SE question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/floating-point-performance-of-classic-minicomputers). The [Whetstone benchmark](http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/whetstone.htm) says a VAX 11/750 is 0.2 MFLOPS (0.0002 GFLOPs) for $47,000 USD. Who knows how much power it draws.

TOP500 list of HPC machines is among the most studied. That project begin in 1993. However, the [power efficiency graphs](https://www.top500.org/statistics/efficiency-power-cores/) only are available recently. While I'm sure you can do order of magnitude estimations, you might get a decade or two of history, not four. (Interestingly, since 1993, the [#1 machine has increased in Flops by 1,000,000x](https://www.top500.org/statistics/perfdevel/).)

Both of these are scientific computing benchmarks, which probably do not resemble the workloads you run.

Just one data point on the current biggest box. [Summit at ORNL is 148 petaflops consuming 10 MW](https://www.top500.org/system/179397), or 14.7 Gflops/W. There is an enormous incentive to increase energy efficiency, because the power density to run 10 MW in a reasonable amount of space is ridiculous.